# What does it mean for a transfer function to have multiple sets of zeros in the numerator?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, state-space

I was looking at the source code for Matlab's `tf2ss` function and I noticed that it parses the numerator assuming that it is a matrix, not a vector. So I looked at the documentation (https://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tf2ss.html?searchHighlight=tf2ss&s_tid=srchtitle) and find the example:
$$
H(s) = \frac{\begin{bmatrix}2s +3\\s^2 +2s+1 \end{bmatrix}}{s^2 + 0.4s +1}
$$
What the heck does this mean? I have never seen a transfer function like this before.

Comment: b - Transfer function numerator coefficients, specified as a vector or matrix. If b is a matrix, then each row of b corresponds to an output of the system.

Answer (score 1):

It describes a SIMO (single input, multiple outputs) system. In your case you  have two outputs, described by the two different numerator polynomials.